# Excel puts a comma-separated set of values in one column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, csv

I have a file which is clearly comma separated but when I open it in Excel 2007 it puts all the data in a single column. I think the problem is with my Windows localization (set to Dutch) but I am not sure. Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: SU606830 question example]

Can you tell me please how to put the values in separate columns?

Comment: Have you tried the Text Import Wizard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in your diagnosis - the .csv Import Wizard in your case is probably expecting semicolons. But this could be all to the good because using Text to Columns can be better (Data > Data Tools > Text to Columns).

Choose Delimited, Delimiters check comma (only), leave `Treat consecutive delimiters as one` blank, ignore Text qualifier and Next. Then be careful about Date format (something the .csv Import Wizard can struggle with).